# Is there a stacking limit for roll bonuses in Apocalypse World?

Tags: apocalypse-world

All *Apocalypse World* rolls are 2d6 + "bonus", with 6 or less counting as a "miss", 7 to 9 counting as "soft hit" and 10 or above counting as "hard hit". Most rolls decide the bonus part by a stat, some use expendable resource (like Angel kit's supply or Barter).

Stats are capped off at +3. Other rolls that allow spending a resource for the bonus (like using the Angel kit's supply, or "dropping jingle to speed an item on its way to you") specify the maximum bonus at +3 too. This has made some of my players assume +3 is the maximum bonus one can get, and they ask me about it. I don't really know, myself.

With +ongoing or +forward, they could get +1 to their roll, and successful help from another character is also +1 (+2 in the previews of Second edition). This would make the total for a helped character with +3 bonus and +forward/+ongoing as high as +5 or +6. Both outcomes are pretty good; +5 would never miss, and be a hard hit 5/6 of the time. +6 never misses either and gets a hard hit 11/12 of times.

I'm not questioning the power of these modifiers; as the GM it's not my job to deny the players bonuses, and I'm pretty sure any character who's got +3 bonus, help and +ongoing has already earned that hard hit. I'm just curious - is there a rule, somewhere, that puts a limit on bonus modifiers placed on a single roll?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope, there are no bonus limits or rules about stacking limitations. Getting +ongoing is hard (and losing it is comparatively easy), and getting +forward is inherently temporary, so high bonuses are hard to get and harder to keep, but when circumstances and clever planning conspire to make them happen, they're legit.

Comment: To back that up, see this post on the official forum http://apocalypse-world.com/forums/index.php?topic=464.msg4276